# how to fix NotImplementedError

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following code to run a vgg

```
checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_filepath+'MAssCalcVGG-noAug.h5', 
        monitor='val_loss', mode='auto', verbose=1, 
        save_best_only=True, save_freq='epoch'
)
#add custom fully-connected network on top of the already-trained base network 
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(conv_base)
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))

#freeze convolutional base 
conv_base.trainable = False

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
            optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3), # lr = 0.0001
            metrics=METRICS) 

#train fully-connected added part 
history = model.fit(train_generat.flow(train_dataset_split,
                                       train_labels_split,
                                       batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                       shuffle=False),
                    steps_per_epoch=len(train_dataset_split) // BATCH_SIZE, 
                    epochs=100,
                    validation_data=valid_generat.flow(valid_dataset_split,
                                       valid_labels_split,
                                       batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                       shuffle=False),
                    validation_steps=len(valid_labels_split) // BATCH_SIZE,
                    callbacks=[es, checkpoint, GarbageCollectorCallback()])
#model.save(save(os.path.join(checkpoint_filepath, 'MAssCalcVGG-noAug.h5'))))

model.summary()
```

but I get this:

```
NotImplementedError: Layer ModuleWrapper has arguments in `__init__` and therefore must override `get_config`
```

how can I fix it?
the code was perfectly working before probably I intentionally made a change to cause this.

Comment: Would you please share your ``conv_base`` layer implementation?

Comment: conv_base = VGG16(weights='imagenet',
                  include_top=False,
                  input_shape=(150, 150, 3))

conv_base.summary()

Comment: Do you get this error when you want to **save** your model (commented line in your question) or without saving model? In which line you get this error?

Comment: without saving it. however, my problem is solved now. I really don't know how :D. maybe it was a minor mistake I did with the checkpoint and call back. because I rewrite them using my old code and now it's woring

Comment: Are you mixing imports between keras and tf.keras? Add all imports to your question.

Comment: @Noushin,is your issue resolved? Else, can you share complete code to replicate your issue?so that we can try to help you. Thanks!